# How to print only the highest value for a key amongst other values?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I run into a problem when attempting to solve this task so I'm here after failing a few times, I was wondering how could I only print the highest value(score) for a key (name) when a key stores multipile values such as:

```
Rob Scored: 3,5,6,2,8
```

So the key would be "Rob" and the values would be his scores above. And I need an output of `Rob Scored: 8` however I still need the dictionary to store the previous scores to then print an average score for each key(name).

So far I have this code and attempted to use `max` however I failed miserably.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dictionary = {}

f = open('ClassA.txt', 'r')
d = {}
for line in f:
    firstpart, secondpart = line.strip().split(':')
    dictionary[firstpart.strip()] = secondpart.strip()
    columns = line.split(": ")
    letters = columns[0]
    numbers = columns[1].strip()
    if d.get(letters):
        d[letters].append(numbers)
    else:
        d[letters] = list(numbers)
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(
sorted((key, list(sorted(vals, reverse=True))) 
       for key, vals in d.items()))
print (sorted_dict)
```

Comment: so whats the problem exactly ?

Comment: Have you  checked what something like `list('3,5,6,2,8')` actually returns?

Comment: What is the problem and what all have you tried so far?

Comment: The problem is the fact that when i print lets say using `max(sorted_dict)` it disables the alphabetical order i established and if i print it without the max then it will print them alphabetically however with all the scores from highest to lowest where i just need the highest.

Comment: @Pythonnnnnnnnn See my answer below. You call `max` on a `list`, not a `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use python's `max` function:

```
dict1 = { "score" : [3,5,6,2,8] }
print("Rob Scored", max(dict1["score"]))
```

Comment: yes but if i have text file of about 20 different names and each of them have several scores will this work if i put it into a loop for each line ?